# What's the propper way to test the react ui including an async rest request?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

My App fetches some data from a rest api using an instance of axios. Now I have a test that looiks like:

```js
it('api call test', async () => {
    act(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <React.StrictMode>
                <App/>
            </React.StrictMode>
            , container);
    });

    const data = {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "bibabo"
    };

    jest.spyOn(api, "get").mockImplementation((url: string, config: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined) => {
        return Promise.resolve({data});
    })
    const main = document.querySelector("main");
    const link = document.querySelector("a[href='/data/1']");
    act(() => {
        link?.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}));
    });
    await wait(() => {
        expect(main?.textContent).toContain("bibabo");
    });
});
```

This test works fine, but i'm a little bit unhappy about using **await wait** especially i'm not sure if this is a case for using **wait**. So is there a better/propper way to test the ajax request?

Comment: It's unknown because you didn't post the code you test. But considering a click triggers asynchronous action that results in ui change, then yes, that's how it's done. The code seems to be specific to react-testing-library but the question doesn't indicate that.

Comment: Yes, the click it triggers an asynchronous action that results in an ui change.